# Get thumbnail from web site with Bing Web Search API

Tags: bing-api

Currently I am working on a website that uses Google search for searching pages in the domain, Google returns a thumbnail from a specific page (Most of the time a random image it finds on the page) together with the search result.

Wanting to move to Bing Web Search API, because google will start adding adds to the result, I was wondering if there was any possibility to get a site's thumbnail together with the search on a specific website? Bing Web Search API Docs says that thumbnails are not supported for all web pages, however there is no clear explanation about how to add one. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for search for your site only, you should use the Bing Custom Search: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/bing-custom-search/. You can create your search instance from customsearch.ai. I see custom search returns thumbnails for (al)most (all) results.

Comment: I looked it up and custom search supports opengraph images, thank you!